# Interval doesn't update text jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I'm using jQuery and setInterval to show countdown in my  element but it doesn't update the text however using console.log I can see that the interval is running properly. Here is the code: 
I call this function in my jQuery:

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration, minutes, seconds,days,hours;
  setInterval(function () {
  days = Math.floor(duration / (60*60*24));
  days_raw = days * (60*60*24);
  hours = Math.floor((duration-days_raw) / (60*60));
  hours_raw = hours * (60*60);
  minutes = Math.floor((duration-(hours_raw + days_raw)) / (60));
  minutes_raw = minutes * (60);
  seconds = Math.floor(duration-(hours_raw + days_raw + minutes_raw));
  seconds_raw = seconds;
  if(days>0)
 {
    if(days===1){
    display.text(days+" Day");
 }
 else
 {
    display.text(days+" Days");}
 }
else if(days<=0)
{   console.log(display);
    display.text(hours+":"+minutes + ":" + seconds);
}

if (--timer < 0) {
  timer = duration;
}
}, 1000);
}
```

And this is my jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$('[data-countdown]').each(function() {
 var $this = $(this), finalDate = $(this).data('countdown');
 startTimer(finalDate,$this);
 });
});
```

The values of .data("countdown") is coming from a php file

Comment: I removed the php tag since this has nothing to do with php at all.

Comment: @Okonomiyaki3000 I'm calling these from my php file

Comment: So what? That's totally irrelevant.

Comment: You have many leaky variables here getting into the global scope. You should put `"use strict";` at the top of your function.

Comment: Can't read code without proper indentation.

Comment: what kind of element is data-countdown attached to?

Comment: @JohnieKarr  I calculate the difference between the start time of an event and current time in unix time. $diff= $upc_tourn['start_t'] -time();  and I set data-countdown="'.$diff.'"

Comment: @Okonomiyaki3000 modifed my code but didn't help

Comment: but what kind of HTML element is data-countdown?  (e.g. span, div, textbox)

Comment: Adding `"use strict";` will not solve anything for you. What it will do is make your code break in places where it is wrong. Use it and then look at your console to find some problems. These are probably not the problems you're having right now but they are problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the value of Duration was not getting changed so I added `duration--; if(duration<0) return;` and it resolved the problem